# Inflate Exception When Running On Android 10

Tags: android

Got this error while running my project on Android 10 device:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.intric8.ereads, PID: 11041
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sample.sample/com.intric8.ereads.ActivityCreateUser}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #139 in com.sample.sample:layout/activity_create_user: Binary XML file line #139 in com.intric8.ereads:layout/activity_create_user: Error inflating class EditText
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3961)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:91)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:149)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:103)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2386)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8178)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #139 in com.sample.sample:layout/activity_create_user: Binary XML file line #139 in com.sample.sample:layout/activity_create_user: Error inflating class EditText
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #139 in com.sample.sample:layout/activity_create_user: Error inflating class EditText
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.sample.sample:drawable/custom_input with resource ID #0x7f0800a9
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/custom_input.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0800a9
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:1157)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:897)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1004)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:1207)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:1182)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5305)
        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1006)
        at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:88)
        at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:84)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:100)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:95)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createEditText(AppCompatViewInflater.java:243)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:160)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1678)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1729)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1071)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1007)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:971)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1133)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1094)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1136)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1094)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1136)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1094)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1136)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1094)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1136)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1094)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1136)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1094)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:692)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:536)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:483)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:775)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:197)
        at com.intric8.ereads.ActivityCreateUser.onCreate(ActivityCreateUser.java:33)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8086)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8074)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1313)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3755)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3961)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:91)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:149)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:103)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2386)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8178)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to ComplexColor: type=0x1
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadComplexColorForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:1433)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadComplexColorFromName(ResourcesImpl.java:1301)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadColorStateList(ResourcesImpl.java:1386)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:1170)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:678)
        at android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.updateGradientDrawableStroke(GradientDrawable.java:1677)
        at android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.inflateChildElements(GradientDrawable.java:1589)
        at android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.inflate(GradientDrawable.java:1404)
        at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:147)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1413)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1402)
        at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflateChildElements(StateListDrawable.java:199)
        at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:126)
        at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:147)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1413)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlForDensity(Drawable.java:1372)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadXmlDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:1224)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:1132)
            ... 50 more
```

custom_input.xml (located in "drawable" folder)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
            <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
            <stroke android:color="@color/material_dynamic_primary50" android:width="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_enabled="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
            <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
            <stroke android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" android:width="1dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

create_activity_user.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    tools:context=".ActivityCreateUser">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imvLogo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="5dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvUser"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/aclonica"
                            android:gravity="right"
                            android:text="NAME"
                            android:textColor="#354259" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvGender"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/aclonica"
                            android:gravity="right"
                            android:text="GENDER"
                            android:textColor="#354259" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvAge"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/aclonica"
                            android:gravity="right"
                            android:text="AGE"
                            android:textColor="#354259" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="5dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/edtName"
                            android:layout_width="250dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/custom_input"
                            android:drawableStart="@drawable/custom_name_icon"
                            android:drawablePadding="12dp"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/llButtonMale"
                            android:layout_width="200dp"
                            android:layout_height="35dp"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/border_button_male"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:padding="5dp">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="40dp"
                                android:layout_height="40dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:orientation="horizontal">

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/baseline_male" />
                            </LinearLayout>

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:orientation="horizontal">

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/txvMale"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/aclonica"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:text="MALE"
                                    android:textColor="#576F72" />
                            </LinearLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/llButtonFemale"
                            android:layout_width="200dp"
                            android:layout_height="35dp"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/border_button_female"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:padding="5dp">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="40dp"
                                android:layout_height="40dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:orientation="horizontal">

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/baseline_female_24" />
                            </LinearLayout>

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:orientation="horizontal">

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/txvFemale"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/aclonica"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:text="FEMALE"
                                    android:textColor="#576F72" />
                            </LinearLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/edtAge"
                            android:layout_width="100dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/custom_input"
                            android:drawableStart="@drawable/custom_age_focused"
                            android:drawablePadding="12dp"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:inputType="textPersonName"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="12dp">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnCreateUser"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/border_button"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/aclonica"
                    android:text="CREATE"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llCreateUserMessage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/border_image"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="invisible">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txvCreateUserMessage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/autour_one"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Name, Gender and Age are required."
                    android:textColor="#7C4DFF"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:visibility="visible" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The project is working properly in Android Studio emulator with Android 12. So I am thinking maybe Android 10 somehow restricting or cannot find specific resources. I provided the custom_input.xml and create_activity_user.xml because they are mentioned in the error log. Also the error mentioned about the edtName (EditText).